# Java Reactor flux filter with inner flux

Tags: java, reactive, reactor, r2dbc

Let's say I have a `Flux<O>` and I want to filter out some of them, but that needs the result of another `Flux`, could not figure out how to do it.

For example

```
private Mono<Boolean> somePredicate(int num) {
   // logic
   return Mono.just(true);
}

Flux<O> flux = Flux.just(1, 2, 3, 4, ...);
flux.filter(n -> somePredicate(n));    // I know it is not right here, but could not figure out
```

Answer (score 1):

You can test each value emitted by your Flux asynchronously using filterWhen:

```
Flux.just( 1, 2, 3, 4).filterWhen( this::somePredicate );
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `flatMap`.

```java
        Flux<Boolean> booleanFlux = Flux.just(1, 2, 3, 4)
                .flatMap(integer -> {
                    /*
                    or if you have a instance you can use method reference like this.
                    flatMap(swService::somePredicate)
                    */
                    return new MyClass().somePredicate(integer);
                });
```

```java
        booleanFlux.subscribe(aBoolean -> {
            System.out.println("aBoolean = " + aBoolean);
        });
```